# Edit text not being displayed on my device, even though no code errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i would be really glad if i i could get some help with this, basically i was following some tutorial on youtube since im a complete beginner on android, not so much on java tho. Basically the code works fine, no visible errors, but when i run it, its not being displayed. Its important to note that the user interface is designed with java, not on XML.

Code:

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.TypedValue;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        EditText username = new EditText(this);
        btn.setId(1);
        username.setId(2);


        RelativeLayout alayout = new RelativeLayout(this);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams drawBtn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        drawBtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        drawBtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams drawUsername;
        drawUsername = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,
            RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL
        );
        drawUsername.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, btn.getId());
        drawUsername.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        drawUsername.setMargins(0,0,0, 15);

        btn.setText("Entrar");
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        alayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);

        Resources r = getResources();
        int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200, r.getDisplayMetrics());

        username.setWidth(px);
        alayout.addView(btn, drawBtn);
        alayout.addView(username, drawUsername);
        setContentView(alayout);
    }
}
```

Also, my btn is actually being displayed, and what intrigues me is why my username EditText isn't, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to -

```
drawUsername = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
```

Why? - `CENTER_HORIZONTAL` or `CENTER_VERTICAL` are rules, you need to set at least some width and height to be drawn. Thats what you did for the button but you didn't do it for the edittext

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the amazing and fast help! that was the exact issue, i didnt notice i wasn't i wasn't wrapping the w and h in the drawUsername constructor

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is due to your RelativeLayout.LayoutParams for your drawerUsername.

If you look at the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams that you've created:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams drawBtn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
drawBtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
drawBtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams drawUsername = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,
        RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
drawUsername.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, btn.getId());
drawUsername.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Notice the difference?
The LayoutParams constructor takes in an int value:

- MATCH_PARENT = -1
- WRAP_CONTENT = -2
- Any other int value

The constructor will do special things if it's -1 or -2, but if it's any other integer value, it'll simply size the width and height to be that size.

If you look at the int value represented by CENTER_HORIZONTAL and CENTER_VERTICAL you'll see it's a value of 14 and 15. Therefore, the LayoutParams constructor will see that and simply create your view with a size of 14 and 15, which is way too tiny to be visible.

The fix, is to replace the drawUsername LayoutParams constructor with WRAP_CONTENT.

Comment: first of all, your answer gives an impression that CENTER_HORIZONTAL is a valid thing to be used though its int value is too small. No CENTER_HORIZONTAL or CENTER_VERTICAL is never a valid parameter for this. Only thing is a coincidence here is CENTER_VERTICAL and CENTER_VERTICAL both are integer which accidentally doesn't give any type cast or invalid param error.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply dude, that also helped me!

Comment: @AmitK.Saha Definitely don't like the way you started with 'first of all'. But no, my answer doesn't give the impression that CENTER_HORIZONTAL is valid to use. Instead, it's simply saying any integer value is possible to use, whether it's a normal int or a constant int. I also explain why WRAP and MATCH is different from other integer values and what happens if another integer value was passed in. Rather than say CENTER_HORIZONTAL isn't meant for this, it's more important to let them know that it is possible, but there are consequences to doing this. They'll just be treated as constants.

Comment: @Jackey, my sincere apology if my comment came out anything less than polite. Sorry again.